# How to use the SEARCH method in OpenAPI?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, openapi, swagger-editor

Does anyone have experience about handling an AcceptVerb (e.g. "search") for a path operation in OpenAPI?  It throws an error because "search" is not of the accepted HTTP methods Swagger Editor accepts.

```yaml
/dnlds/bwaaccount:
    summary: Searches for BOSS accounts
    description: >-
      Receives a BOSS search request and then the API will search the BOSS database.
    search:
```

This is my method signature in my API:

```cs
[AcceptVerbs("SEARCH")]
public HttpResponseMessage Search()
```

Answer (score 0):

As of v. 3.1, OpenAPI Specification only supports these methods: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS, TRACE.

SEARCH, QUERY, and other methods are not supported.

There are existing feature requests to support other HTTP methods, including SEARCH:

- [Support for SEARCH http method](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1306)
- [Support all HTTP Methods](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1747)

Can you change the implementation to use GET or POST instead of SEARCH?

If not, one workaround to define the SEARCH method as an `x-` [extension](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/openapi-extensions/):

```yaml
paths:
  /dnlds/bwaaccount:
    summary: Searches for BOSS accounts

    x-search:  # <-------
      summary: ...
      operationId: ...
      parameters: [...]
      responses:
        ...
```

If you generate the OpenAPI definition from code, this would require adjusting your framework/library to generate `x-search` instead of `search`.

However, `x-` extensions are just metadata, so this workaround won't actually give you SEARCH support in OpenAPI-based tooling such as Swagger UI, OpenAPI Generator, and others.