# Is it possible to extend Swagger/Swashbuckle to consume a new Http Method?

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

Im working on an api project that uses swashbuckle/swagger in .net core 7.

How ever i have come across an issue whereby a GET request is not suitable as the query length is limited. And other Http request method types are not suitable.

What i did find was SEARCH http request method [source](https://httptoolkit.com/blog/http-search-method/)
Which seems like a reasonable combination between GET / POST.

I have implemented a custom HttpMethodAttribute to support 'SEARCH'
And this works when the frontend call the endpoint with the method type 'SEARCH'

However Swagger UI errors out when rendering it...understandable, but i wonder if it was possible to extend it and be able to render it.

Failing that what are the alternatives to a GET request with a very long query? without changing the app settings.

Cheers

EDIT: @stuartd correctly pointed out that the verb is now 'QUERY'
However i still have the same issue with trying to display this endpoint in swagger

Comment: The link you provide links to the [IETF proposal](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-httpbis-safe-method-w-body/?include_text=1) which suggests the verb is now `QUERY`

Comment: POST with data in the body instead of in Query Parameters?

Comment: @Ralf POST suggests creating something, and thats not what im doing. Im essentually getting data with a query, but GET has a limited length for a query

Comment: I've definitely seen examples of adding custom verbs to swagger, but having trouble finding right now

Comment: Then you have already an API that can handle that verb? Swagger is just a description of an API so presumably can be taught to show mostly everything. But can your API handle it?

Comment: @Ralf Yeah thats true, but im working on the endpoints and swaggers being used for documenting. The endpoints will be consumed by other developers so it would be useful to have that documented.

Comment: Looking at the [OpenAPI](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/versions/3.1.0.md#fixed-fields-7) specification the verbs are more or less hard coded in the specs. Would have thought  the HTTP Verb is just a token that can be changed to whatever needed but the specification has explicit objects for the different verbs that need to be fullfilled. So looks like you are bound to those mentioned there.

Comment: Another thing. It may be uncommon but for example Elasticsearch uses GET with a Body for querying stuff https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html

Comment: Does this answer your question -- [How to use the SEARCH method in OpenAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72493449/113116)

Answer (score 0):

Have settled with @Ralf's solution (quoted below) to use a POST method to display it in Swagger.

> POST with data in the body instead of in Query Parameters?
> Looking at the OpenAPI specification, the verbs are more or less hard coded in the specs. Would have thought the HTTP Verb is just a token that can be changed to whatever needed but the specification has explicit objects for the different verbs that need to be fulfilled. So looks like you are bound to those mentioned there.